# Iterating through a single ActiveRecord object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 4.2

User.all do |u|
  puts u.first
  puts u.last
  ....
end
```

Instead of individually iterating through each element in u, is there was a way to iterate?

This will not work:

```
u.each do |e|
  ...
end
```

Comment: What's your use-case for trying to do this? In any event, `User.where(id: 1)` will return you an enumerable object if that's truly what you're after.

Comment: Do you want to iterate trough the `User` attributes? If yes, you can iterate with the `attributes`, so `u.attributes.each do ...`

Comment: Yes. attributes is what I was looking for.